# How i get that message (Please fill out this field) using selenium-webdriver- java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am unable to handle the context text of an Username and Password fields.

Whenever I Click the Login button without entering Username and Password, I am getting text 'Please fill out this field' in a context box. I couldn't handle that using webdriver. HTML code for the Username field as below.

Screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwY1ugu4CKGQV1gxcGl6X21WWWs/view?usp=sharing

I want text of the marked context box.

I want to print the text of the context box.

Answer (score 1):

@saiKrishna: I do not know how did you implemented your code, for me i would have tried

Step1: On Leaving a Username field blank or Directly clicking on Login Button I assume that the Context message is thrown. Perform any action that will open context menu. 
Step2: Manually move the header to the pixel postion id the context menu position is not changing , then handle the context menu pop-up and take header on it. 
Step3: One we get the control of context menu we can easily get the context text by gettext method.

Please let me know if there is any other condition or change which we cannot implement.

Comment: Hi shinde,sry for the late .comming to the point u mention that header in step2 i didn't understand what's that header u mean is it  curser

Comment: Header i mean Mouse Pointer.

Comment: it doesn't show any pixel's in the context menu position.They wrote required = "required" in the html code.so im unable to get pixels in that position.

Comment: Is the site publicly Available If yes, Can you give me the URL and If not, Can you locate the context pop-up using Tool like Firebug?

Comment: sry this site is not avilable publicly.No,we cant locate context popup using firebug.when i trying to locate that(context box),it's disappering.

Comment: Here is the option by which you can get the Xpath for Context box. Open the Context Box and do not try to inspect element. Just press 'Shift+Ctrl+C' Together. I hope then you can perform inspect element on the Context Box. Also can you show the HTML Code for the context menu option.

Comment: hi shinde,it dosen't inspect that context box when i press 'Shift+Ctrl+C'. There is no particular code for context menu option,they mention it in username text box code <input id="username" type="text" required="required" name="username">.I send the screeshot with code in my question pls check that.